# Existence and uniqueness of solution of : $y'(x) = (x-y(x))^{4/5}, \space y(3)=3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, lipschitz-functions, initial-value-problems

> Study the Existence and Uniqueness of the IVP :
>   $$y'(x) = (x-y(x))^{4/5}, \space y(3)=3$$

Regarding existence, I'd first assume $f$ the function such :

$$f(x,y)=(x-y)^{4/5}$$

We observe that $f(x,y)$ is **not** continuous in $
\mathbb R^2$ since we need $x-y\geq0$.

Letting $D$ be a domain such :

$$D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2: |x-3| \leq ε_1, \space |y-3|\leq ε_2 \}$$

we can say that there exists $ε_1,ε_2 \in \mathbb R$ such that $f$ is continuous in $D$, which means that the IVP has a solution in $D$.

**Question :** Is the above statement correct ? Shall I go into more details explaining why $f$ can be continuous in such a domain ?

Finally, regarding uniqueness, I know that showing that $f(x,y)=(x-y)^{4/5}$ is a *Lipschitz* function is enough. :

$$|f(x,y_2) -f(x,y_1)|=|(x-y_2)^{4/5}-(x-y_1)^{4/5}|$$

The function $g(y)=(x-y)^{4/5}$ is continuous in the interval $[y_1,y_2]$ with $y_1,y_2 \in D_f$ and $g$ is also differentiable in $(y_1,y_2)$ , which means that we can apply the *Mean Value Theorem* and yield :

$$g'(ξ)=\frac{g(y_2)-g(y_1)}{y_2-y_1}\Rightarrow \bigg|\frac{4}{5(x-ξ)^{1/5}}\bigg||y_2-y_1|=|(x-y_2)^{4/5}-(x-y_1)^{4/5}|$$

Here, we can see that there isn't a bound for the expression $\bigg|\frac{4}{5(x-ξ)^{1/5}}\bigg|$, thus meaning that the solution **is not unique**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f(x,y) := (x-y)^{4/5}$ is continuous is $\mathbb{R}^2$, being the composition of the continuous functions $\phi(t) := t^{4/5} = \sqrt[5]{t^4}$, $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $g(x,y) := x-y$, $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

By Peano's existence theorem, the Cauchy problems associated with $f$ do have solutions.

The function $f$ is not (locally) Lipschitz continuous, but this is only a sufficient condition in order to get uniqueness of solution of Cauchy problems.

It is easy to see that $y(x)$ is a solution of $y'=f(x,y)$ if and only if 
$z(x) := y(x) - x$ is a solution of $z' = h(x,z)$, with $h(x,z) := z^{4/5} - 1$.
In particular, $y(x)$ is a solution of the given Cauchy problem if and only if $z(x) := y(x) - x$ is a solution of the Cauchy problem
$$
\begin{cases}
z' = z^{4/5} - 1,\\
z(3) = 0.
\end{cases}
$$
This Cauchy problem admits, locally, a unique solution, implicitly defined by
$$
\int_0^z \frac{1}{s^{4/5}-1}\, ds = x-3.
$$
It can be proved (but this requires a simple qualitative study) that this unique local solution can be prolonged to a unique global solution.

Comment: but what about $y=x$ what I am missing?

Comment: It is not a solution: indeed $y' = 1$, so the equation is not satisfied.

Comment: The function $f(x,y) = (x-y)^{4/5}$ is **not** continuous in $\mathbb R^2$ since the domain of it is : $D_f = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x \geq y\}$.

Comment: ahh you re right my crelesness thanks for clarification

Comment: @Rebellos: that function is continuous in $\mathbb{R}^2$ since, by definition, is $\sqrt[5]{(x-y)^4}$.

Comment: @Rigel [WA Link showing properties](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(x,y)+%3D+(x-y)%5E(4%2F5))

Comment: That's a problem of WA, not mine, see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(x,y)+%3D+((x-y)%5E4)%5E(1%2F5)

Comment: You're indeed correct, I was confused by it. Thanks for your answer, nicely stated and explained. Dunno who down voted though.

Comment: **Update :** The function is **NOT** continuous. As explained down below, the property **does not hold** in the case of $x-y<0$. I still do not understand how would one show the existence. This seems like a really tight theoritical issue regarding the exercise right here that totally messes it all up.

Comment: Whatever definition of $t^{4/5}$ you are going to use, the function $f$ is continuous in its domain of definition.

Comment: @Rigel True, but you still need to implement a definition, which doesn't seem as good and straight-forward way of solving an exercise that is also included in books/exams. For me, the exercise has a huge black hole and is really tight in details, so it just seems as a bad exercise in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

The function $f$ is not defined in your set $D$ since $D$ contains points where $x<y$. So your statement is not correct.

Also for uniqueness, the theorem says that if $f$ is Lipschitz in $y$, then the solution is unique, but the converse is not true. So you cannot say that since $f$ is not Lipschitz, there is no uniqueness.

It is true that one could define $t^{4/5}=(t^4)^{1/5}$ but then you lose important properties like $t^{ab}=(t^a)^b$. In general it is better not to define $t^a$ if $a$ is a rational and $t<0$.
A way out in this case would be to extend $f$ to be zero in the region $x<y$. So now the problem $y'(x)=f(x,y)$, $y(3)=3$ has a solution since $f$ is continuous in $\mathbb R^2$. Then you can follow Riegel's proof to get existence and show that the solution that you get stays in the region $x-y\ge 0$ so it is a solution of your original equation.

Comment: The definition of $t^{4/5}$ can be a matter of taste. Anyway, in my personal experience, if it is given a power with a fixed rational exponent (i.e., I am not referring to functions like $x^x$), then the most common interpretation is the one that I have given. Anyway, one can proceed as you have shown.

Comment: Agree. If you decide to define $t^{4/5}$ for $t$ negative then yours is the only possible definition. My point is that it is better not to define it, since it creates too many mistakes. Students are so used to properties like $(t^a)^b=t^{ab}$ or $t^a=e^{\log t^a}=e^{a\log t}$, which clearly fail if you extend the definition of $t^{4/5}$ to negative numbers. When I teach analysis, I do not define it. But yeah, it is a matter of taste.

Comment: @Gio67: very good explanation. so these equalities are not true $t^{4/5}= (t^4)^{1/5}=(t^{1/5})^4$  for negative $t$ values.

Comment: The elaboration and explanation of Gio67 is exactly the reason for which I argued about the continuity (and probably the reason WA shows the property I elaborated in my question form).

Comment: @Gio: but we use $(-1)^{1/5}=-1$ for reals without considering other complex roots.

Comment: @daulomb This is mistaken though.There are 4 more complex roots of course.

Comment: The typical example of what could go wrong is $i=(-1)^{1/2}=(-1)^{2/4}=((-1)^{2})^{1/4}=1^{1/4}=1$.